# Unichar do not display in PBI Report Server

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

Some unichar values is not displayed in Power BI Report Server.

The following works in Power BI Desktop for Report Server.

[image]

When saving to the Report Server, the last arrow is not visible.

[image]

Maybe something to do with size?
Is there a setting on the report or the Report Server that may lead to this?

Comment: It could be that the font being used in the server doesn't have that character.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by Edge running in Internet Explorer mode.

I tried to open the report while remote desktop on different servers, while also pasting the character into different applications on the server (address bar in IE, notepad, paint).
The character never worked in Internet Explorer even if I could paste it into the address bar.

[image]

However, it worked with Edge even if I could not paste the character into other applications.

(The report where running on the same report server)